# CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: cuda, yolo

I am testing YOLOv4 on a Custom Dataset as described at https://blog.roboflow.ai/training-yolov4-on-a-custom-dataset/, using google Colab (refer to https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mzL6WyY9BRx4xX476eQdhKDnd_eixBlG#scrollTo=GNVU7eu9CQj3). The cuda and opencv information are:

```
 CUDA-version: 10010 (10010), cuDNN: 7.6.5, GPU count: 1  
 OpenCV version: 3.2.0
 Prepare additional network for mAP calculation...
 compute_capability = 370, cudnn_half = 0
```

!nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   62C    P8    30W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                 ERR! |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The cuda errors are:

```
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/blas_kernels.cu : () : line: 841 : build time: Jun 18 2020 - 13:22:47 

 CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device: File exists
darknet: ./src/utils.c:325: error: Assertion `0' failed.
```

Comment: you compiled with the wrong flags (i.e. not for your cc/sm). e.g. you could have used `compute_35,code=sm_35` but be using a RTX 2080 GPU.

Comment: Thanks! then what should I set for the cc/sm?

Comment: Depends on your GPU. Or you can list all possible cases and compile for all GPUs, up to you

Comment: compute_capability = 370 means a compute 3.7 device, i.e. a Tesla  K40 or K80. See linked duplicate